# Why is this regex expression returning 'true'?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this exact regex in a RegularExpressionValidator and it works fine. However this code in c# is returning true. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

I am checking for numbers only regex

```
var x = Regex.IsMatch("1234asdf", @"[0-9]+").ToString();
```

Comment: Of course it returns true. Why shouldn't it? I don't know what that RegularExpressionValidator is you are mentioning, but perhaps that RegularExpressionValidator had a setting (which was enabled) that made it anchoring the regex to the start and end of the string...

Comment: It matches because the `Regex.IsMatch` API tries to find a match of the pattern in _any_ portion of the input string.  If you want to enforce that the entire string input matches, then use the pattern `^[0-9]+$`.  This would match an input consisting only of digits.

Comment: Because it will match the digits only. You have not told it to match the whole string.

Comment: `[0-9]+` means "one or more digits", and we have `1234` match for the pattern; do you mean `"^[0-9]+$"` pattern? (one or more digits *only*)

Comment: `RegularExpressionValidator` adds anchoring if you didn't anchor it yourself. It will make sure that there are no characters which did not match the regex. In order to do that yourself, you have to add in the anchors, as @Tim said.

Comment: because it matches the value

Comment: You guys are so awesome! Thank you. ASP.NET has a RegularExpressionValidator which you can attach to a text box. The regex I included in the question somehow works just fine when used in that control. But will fix this on the code behind. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @canton7!

Answer (score 4):

Because is finding what you're looking for inside the provided string.
You have tyo use `^` and `$` to force the whole string to mathc the regex:

`^[0-9]+$`

`^` matches the beginning, `$`, the end of the string

Please, look ath the Anchors section of this doc: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

BTW, instead of `[0-9]` you should use `\d`

Comment: Worth mentioning why `RegularExpressionValidator` doesn't need its regex anchoring, as that's half of the question?

Comment: side note: in c# `\d` means any *unicode* digit (including, say, *persian ones*), `[0-9]` is often a safier option; or put it as `Regex.IsMatch("1234asdf", @"^\d+$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);`

Comment: There is no `RegularExpressionValidator`. This is an static method of `Regex` class, which has no configuration at all: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_System_String_

Comment: I'm assuming he's using the one in System.Web: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @canton7 I'm assuming nothing: I'm reading the code and I clearly read `Regex.IsMatch`. And that's the method for which I've included the reference link. I'm sorry, but your asusmption is wrong ;)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I had never thought of that, and you're right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#decimal-digit-character-d " includes the standard decimal digits 0-9 as well as the decimal digits of a number of other character set"

Comment: I think his question is perfectly clear: "This regex works in RegularExpressionValidator, but not in Regex.Match. Why?". I've added my own answer, anyway.

Comment: @canton7 Now I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers talk about why your regex needs to be anchored. However, nobody's picked up on the `RegularExpressionValidator` part of your question.

I'm assuming you mean [`System.Web.RegularExpressionValidator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator?view=netframework-4.8). RegularExpressionValidator does more than just checking whether the regex matches - it also checks whether the regex is an exact match. That is, it effectively adds the `^` and `$` anchoring for you.

[The code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/RegularExpressionValidator.cs,95):

```
Match m = RegexUtil.Match(controlValue, ValidationExpression, RegexOptions.None, MatchTimeout);
return(m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == controlValue.Length);
```

Note how it checks `m.Success`, but also checks that the match starts at the beginning of the value being checked, and ends at the end of the value being checked.

([`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,74) does the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Because you trying to match one or more digit from 0 to 9. Explaininh:

```
[0-9] //Match digit 0-9 you can also use /d-(Match any digit char)
+ //Match one or more of the preceding token
```

If you have some digit in you string, this code:

```
var x = Regex.IsMatch("1234asdf", @"[0-9]+").ToString();
```

will always return True.
For exaple if you try this one:

```
var x = Regex.IsMatch("asdf", @"[0-9]+").ToString();
```

will return False

Answer (score -1):

You have to use ^ and $ to force the whole string to match the regex pattern

^[0-9]+$

^ matches the beginning, $ the end of the string

In C# Write the expression like below format:

```
var x = Regex.IsMatch("1234", @"^[0-9]+$").ToString();
```

Comment: try adding an explanation to your answer